# Lighttpd Mod-Rewrite Rule Matching All Subdomains

Tags: mod-rewrite, lighttpd

I am using `lighttpd` web server and `mod_write` and have a simple host match expression:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "domain\.com$" {
}
```

The problem is this is matching `test.domain.com` as well. How do I modify the expression to only match http://domain.com but not any subdomains such as test.domain.com?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com$" {
```

The `^` character specifies that the start of the string must be at this position; it won't match if there's anything before `domain`.